# PasswordBox Bindings

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core

Что я неправильно делаю? View:

```
<PasswordBox Name="SecretKey">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="PasswordChanged">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SecretKeyChangedCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=SecretKey}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</PasswordBox>
```

ViewModel:

```
private void ExecutePasswordChangedCommand(PasswordBox obj)
    {
        if (obj != null)
            Password = obj.Password;
        log.Debug(Password);
    }
```

Я новичок во всем этом и наверняка я что-то не так делаю. По крайней мере меня смущает то, что я нигде не говорю про этот метод, поэтому логично что он никогда не произойдет.

Сам ViewModel, в котором я хочу ловить пароль наследуется от:

```
public class MainVM : BindableBase
```

Единственное что мне нужно - передать в MainVM значение. Можно по кнопке или как угодно.

Comment: Что за MVVM фреймворк используете? Класс `BindableBase` откуда взят? DevExpress? Пишите такие штуки сразу в вопросе, потому что приходится ванговать и гадать, как у вас приложение построено. Вам нужно пароль каждый символ ввода обновлять в VM, верно?

Comment: `using Prism.Mvvm;` , Обновлять можно и по кнопке разом. Хотя лучше каждый символ ввода, думаю.

Comment: Расскажите, куда вы эти данные потом отправляете, в каком формате и какой алгоритм хэширования для пароля вы используете на сервере?

Comment: А это имеет значение? Мне для начала достаточно будет в лог вывести

Comment: Пароль в открытом виде? Зачем он вам? Вся эта длинная и мутная история с `PasswordBox` и проблемами при его привязке связана именно с тем, что преобразовывать пароль в строку - небезопасно, потому что эта строка попадет в память и неизвестно сколько там будет лежать. Оке, правильней всего замутить сразу из этого пароля хэш вычитав побайтово из `SecureString`, но я вам покажу и как в лог это вывести в открытом виде, но для начала скажите, какой алгоритм хеширования используется у пароля, чтобы я смог дать вам правильный совет.

Comment: Ну тогда давайте md5

Comment: То есть выбрали самый дырявый хеш, давайте уж Sha256 тогда?

Comment: Хорошо, давайте sha256

Comment: Последний вопрос, у вас .NET Core 3.1 или .NET 5 или Framework?

Comment: У меня .Net Core 3.1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`PasswordBox` так задуман, чтобы не хранить вводимый пароль в `string`, так как `string` является неизменяемым (immutable) типом и может храниться неуправляемое количество времени в памяти. Чтобы этого избежать, разработчики WPF пошли на изврат (который сами же потом [признали](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/30612)) - `SecureString`. Но несмотря на то, что они всеми силами попытаются избавиться от `SecureString`, при использовании `PasswordBox` без него не обойтись. Ну если конечно хочется сохранить безопасность на уровне.

Так как я не знаю `Prism.Mvvm`, я попробую угадать правильный код, но не гарантирую, что в нем не будет ошибок, если что - поправьте.

И первое, что я вам предложу сделать (ради безопасности конечно) - **сознательно нарушить MVVM**. То есть передать ссылку на экземпляр `PasswordBox` в View Model.

```xml
<StackPanel>
    <PasswordBox Name="PwdBox"/>
    <Button Content="Submit" Command="{Binding SumbitCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=PwdBox}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

А код View Model будет такой

```cs
private ICommand _submitCommand;

public ICommand SumbitCommand => _submitCommand ??= new DelegateCommand<object>(parameter => 
{ 
    PasswordBox box = (PasswordBox)parameter;

    // безопасный способ получить хэш
    string password = GetSecureHash(box.SecurePassword);
    log.Debug(password);

    // НЕБЕЗОПАСНЫЙ способ получить хэш
    string password2 = HashToString(SHA256.HashData(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(box.Password)));
    log.Debug(password2);
}, parameter => parameter is PasswordBox box && box.SecurePassword.Length > 0);

private string GetSecureHash(SecureString secureString)
{
    SHA256 sha256 = SHA256.Create();
    Span<byte> hashBytes = stackalloc byte[sha256.HashSize >> 3];
    IntPtr ptr = Marshal.SecureStringToBSTR(secureString);
    unsafe
    {
        ReadOnlySpan<byte> source = new ReadOnlySpan<byte>((void*)ptr, secureString.Length * sizeof(char));
        sha256.TryComputeHash(source, hashBytes, out _);
    }
    Marshal.ZeroFreeBSTR(ptr);
    return HashToString(hashBytes);
}

private string HashToString(ReadOnlySpan<byte> bytes)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(bytes.Length * 2);
    for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
        sb.Append(bytes[i].ToString("x2"));
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Безопасность безопасного способа заключается в том, что мы получаем доступ к данным `SecureString` на ровно нужное нам время, а затем использованный участок памяти затираем нулями `Marshal.ZeroFreeBSTR`.

Директива `unsafe` позволяет работать напрямую с памятью как в C++, но требует разрешение на использование небезопасного кода. В свойствах проекта вам нужно будет поставить галочку "Разрешить небезопасный код", иначе `unsafe` не скомпилируется.

НЕБЕЗОПАСНЫЙ способ получить пароль создает `string` в памяти с открытым паролем, то есть сводит все старания разработчиков WPF достичь требуемого уровня безопасности на нет.

Мой вывод в лог показывает, что оба способа работают одинаково

```
06e44dc1b95c469f43aaccb49e93c36827626266eed5575eced74af9a016c9cd
06e44dc1b95c469f43aaccb49e93c36827626266eed5575eced74af9a016c9cd
```

Почему я не передал в команду как аргумент `SecurePassword` - да потому что это не работает, в команду прилетит пустой экземпляр данного класса, то же самое и с `Password`.

Почему я не передаю пароль каждый раз когда он изменяется а считываю только по кнопке - потому что зачем?

P.S. Используемая кодировка при генерации хэша - родная кодировка для `string` в C# `Encoding.Unicode` или по-другому она называется `UTF-16`. Но код можно доработать для использования `UTF-8`, если это критично, например, если вы хотите считать хеши паролей не только в этом приложении, а где-то еще, например на сайте при авторизации в этот же сервис.