# Как изменить конкретные символы в label?

Tags: c#, wpf

[image]

По умолчанию у меня `Label` содержит контент `0/0`, но при вводе получается вот так:

[image]

После ввода в текстовое поле, у меня `Label` показывает количество введённых символов.

Как сделать, что бы менялся 1 символ в `Label`, а не всё содержимое? То есть вот к примеру: было `0/0`, ввели `фыв`, cтало `3/0`.

Сам код вот:

```cs
private void pbPas_PasswordChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    labP.Content = pbPas.Password.Length.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}

private void tbLog_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    labL.Content = tbLog.Text.Length.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
```

Comment: Поймите вы наконец то, что разрабатываете проект по правилам WinForms! Это неправильно, ибо WPF это привязки и XAML со своими стилями, это минимальный набор любого проекта WPF! Также `Lable` в WPF не используется, ибо там замена есть в виде `TextBlock`. Ну а по вопросу, вы сами себе геморрой придумали, ибо эта циферка `3` ведь не строка, верно? Так почему вы ее пихаете в строку? Мы вам уже под каждым вопросом говорим о ваших проблемах, но вы тупо нас игнорируете, будто мы клоуны какие-то, которые вас тут веселят. Чтож, будем значит и вас игнорировать в дальнейшем...

Comment: Я wpf использую как разметку программы, всю логику я через c# прописываю. Ибо я не знаю пока как логику в wpf писать.

Comment: Цифра 3 это content у Label, он меняется в зависемости от введённых количество символов в текстовом поле. И я бы хотел просто 1 символ менять у Label, а не весь Content.  И я знаю что есть TextBlock.   Я смотрел про них, и они не чем не отличаются друг от друга.

Comment: `Я wpf использую как разметку программы` - это мы вам уже говорим почти под каждым вопросом, а вы пропускаете мимо ушей и игнорируете, не желая даже хоть немного попытаться сделать проект правильно. Вы же учитесь, так учитесь сразу правильно! `Цифра 3 это content у Label` - то есть `Lable` у вас хранит данные, а должен их брать из простого `int`. `они не чем не отличаются друг от друга` - ой ошибаетесь. `TextBlock` как минимум не контрол, он `FrameworkElement`, который предназначен для отображения текста, не более. А `Lable`, это `ContentControl`, что дает свои тонкости.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решение в лоб, невзирая на то, что вы пошли неверным путём при организации структуры приложения WPF. Что ж, учитесь, разбирайтесь. Если интересно узнать WPF поближе, почитайте про шаблон проектирования MVVM и привязки данных.

```
string text = labP.Content.ToString();
string[] parts = text.Contains('/') ? text.Split('/') : new string[] { "0", "0" };
labP.Content = $"{pbPas.Password.Length}/{parts[1]}";
```

Или если второе значение - константа, можно так, по-простому:

```cs
labP.Content = $"{pbPas.Password.Length}/0";
```

В WPF не рекомендуется использовать `Label` для отображения текста, вместо него рекомендуется использовать `TextBlock`. У него к тому же есть свойтво `Text`, которое содержит `string`, и его не надо приводить к строке через `.ToString()`.

А по поводу того, что свойство `Password` у `PasswordBox` использовать нельзя (это небезопасно), я писал [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1245131/373567).

---

**Обновлено**

> Ну задумка следущая. `TextBlock` содержит текст 0/30 30 - это максимальное количесво вводимых символов.

Ну тогда это делается без единой строчки C# кода, в XAML разметке. Можно даже например перекрасить `30/30` в красный цвет, когда оно достигнет этого значения.

```xml
<StackPanel>
    <TextBox x:Name="TextBoxLogin" MaxLength="30"/>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
        <StackPanel.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Text.Length, ElementName=TextBoxLogin}" Value="30">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </StackPanel.Resources>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text.Length, ElementName=TextBoxLogin, StringFormat={}{0}/}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding MaxLength, ElementName=TextBoxLogin}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

Или по совету @EvgeniyZ еще так можно:
*(результат одинаковый)*

```xml
<StackPanel>
    <TextBox x:Name="TextBoxLogin" MaxLength="30"/>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Right">
        <TextBlock.Style>
            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Text.Length, ElementName=TextBoxLogin}" Value="30">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TextBlock.Style>
        <Run Text="{Binding Text.Length, ElementName=TextBoxLogin, Mode=OneWay}"/>/<Run Text="{Binding MaxLength, ElementName=TextBoxLogin}"/>
    </TextBlock>
</StackPanel>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Понял, спасибо. Ну теперь можно забывать про Label :)

Comment: А, окей. Щя тогда везде слелаю)

Comment: Если использовать такой костыль, то вообще бессмысленно строку разбивать, просто при изменении значения делать `labP.Content = $"{pbPas.Password.Length}/{parts[1]}";` да и все.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ кто его знает, может там второе значение, которое будет меняться где-то в другом месте, автор же не объяснил, что именно он делает. Я просто подсказал как изменить один кусок строки, оставив в покое другой. "Решение в лоб". А так, вы правы, конечно.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ дополнил ответ.

Comment: `там второе значение, которое будет меняться где-то в другом месте` ну сейчас четко видно, что делает автор. Он просто написал `0/10` и работает дальше везде с этой строкой, как с набором данных, изменяя первое значение, он не понимает, что эти 0 и 10, должны быть не в строке, а в отдельных переменных. Короче, автор делает костыли, покрывает еще сильнее костылями, а подумать о нормальном решение не хочет)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ спору нет, но опять же, автор не указал в вопросе, что именно он делает.

Comment: @aepot Ну задумка следущая.

**TextBlock содержит текст 0/30**

30 - это максимальное количесво вводимых символов. Как ограничить ввод максимальным числом символов я через разметку знаю

А **0** это покозатель введённых символов в текстовом поле, то есть число растёст когда мы вводим что либо в текстовое поле.

Comment: @Кирилл Вам тут ни единой строчки кода не нужно, услышьте вы нас, научитесь использовать привязки!! Вот вся ваша задача, простой [XAML](https://pastebin.com/31BqUivD), без каких либо событий и чего либо еще, привязки и XAML...

Comment: @Кирилл обновил ответ

Comment: @aepot, о спасибо. Теперь буду пробывать в xaml пихать всё

Comment: @EvgeniyZ прикольная задумка кстати с `Run`, я так никогда не делал. Но попробовал и не понял, как между элементами `Run` убрать пробелы. В вашем примере кстати у слеша пробелы не нужны, WPF их автоматом добавляет.

Comment: @aepot Конечно, хотяб не костыли. Единственное, `Value="30"` статично, надо его привязать к `MaxLength`. `как между элементами Run убрать пробелы` - тут все дело в том, что все, что пишется между `<TextBlock>...</TextBlock>` является текстом, то есть можно написать хоть `<TextBlock><Run Text="Текст"/> Другой текст</TextBlock>` и в итоге это все соединит и будет `Текст Другой текст`, из за этого, любая новая строка будет приравниваться к пробелу. Чтоб его убрать, надо либо писать все на одной строке, либо можно сделать [такое](https://pastebin.com/WCTXLRXp).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ ах вон оно что, ну буду знать. :) А прибиндить значение триггера с ходу я не смог. `XamlParseException: 'A 'Binding' cannot be set on the 'Value' property of type 'DataTrigger'. A 'Binding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject.'` Но не стал разбираться.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, @aepot, все же способ повлиять на обработку пробелов есть, см. статью: [Обработка пробелов в XAML](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/desktop/xaml-services/white-space-processing), собственно, из нее следует, что это поведение в `TextBlock` не оригинальное, а переопределенное, при оригинальном поведении пробелов там быть не должно. Но как вот вернуть поведение к оригинальному пока не понятно, много чего во фреймворке сделано нерасширяемым и реализовано как internal. Я пробовал сделать наследника `Run` и пометить его атрибутом `TrimSurroundingWhitespace`, но это почему-то не сра