# Как получить пароли из нескольких PasswordBox при реализации MVVM (смена пароля пользователем)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

хочу реализовать окно смены пароля, используя MVVM. В окне есть 3 PasswordBox. Как мне вытянуть инфу из всех трёх в команду, чтобы не нарушать MVVM. Когда PasswordBox был 1, то я его передавал как CommandParameter
`Command="{Binding AutorisationCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=pwdBox}"`

Что делать в моем случае?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Просто в тему https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1245131/373567

Comment: Вам нужны `MultiBinding`+`IMultiValueConverter`

Comment: Я предполагал что в это упрётся, просто не хочется переписывать LambdaCommand, но только вот при таком подходе я ещё не нашёл как не делать свойства для хранения сконвертированных данных...Чтобы не нарушать принцип безопасности.

Comment: Вам не нужно переписывать команду, она и так object принимает, вы туда хоть массив паролей передавайте, хоть окно целиеом. Почитайте про мультибиндинг. Это все решается написанием конвертера и мультипривязкой в xaml. Как не нарушить безопасность - ссылка выше. Задача очень простая, я просто с телефона - не смогу вас кодом порадовать.

Comment: наверное не очень правильно такое советовать, но я бы просто тупо всю модель для смены пароля кинул в команду со всеми введенными в неё данными

Comment: `MWWM` => `MVVM`

Comment: @tym32167 всю вьюху вы имели в виду? Было бы не очень удобно пассвордбоксы из нее выковыривать. Пришлось бы либо по именам, либо по визуальному дереву. Кмк, логичнее просто 3 штуки закинуть в конвертер.

Comment: @aepot не, я имел ввиду модель или вьюмодель, что то, у чего уже есть поля, заполненные юзером.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По итогу реализовал IMultiValueConverter и при помощи MultiBinding реализовал передачу паролей как массив.
Класс конвертера:

```
internal class pwdConverter : IMultiValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            PasswordBox[] pwdBoxes = new PasswordBox[3];
            pwdBoxes[0] = values[0] as PasswordBox;
            pwdBoxes[1] = values[1] as PasswordBox;
            pwdBoxes[2] = values[2] as PasswordBox;
            return pwdBoxes;
        }

        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Код кнопки:

```
<Button Content="Подтвердить"
                    Grid.Column="0"
                    IsDefault="True"
                    Command="{Binding ConfirmChangePasswordCommand}">
                <Button.CommandParameter>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource pwdConverter}">
                        <Binding ElementName="OldPwdBox"/>
                        <Binding ElementName="NewPwdBox"/>
                        <Binding ElementName="ConfirmNewPwdBox"/>
                    </MultiBinding>
                </Button.CommandParameter>
            </Button>
```

В самой команде уже идёт приведение типа массива и работа с полями пароля.