# Blazor wasm пароль не в SecureString?

Tags: c#, безопасность, spa, blazor

Просматривая примеры из авторизаций на blazor, нигде не видел использования SecureString, как я давным-давно делал еще в WPF. Почему? Разве хранить пароль в простом string это безопасно? Если это безопасно, то почему тогда в WPF/UWP(думаю тоже) желательно использовать SecureString, а в Blazor нет? Не подвергается ли обычный стринг xss-атаке, если рассматриваем SPA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Рекомендации Microsoft насчет использования SecureString изменились: [DE0001: SecureString shouldn't be used](https://github.com/dotnet/platform-compat/blob/master/docs/DE0001.md)

- Содержимое SecureString по настоящему шифруется только под Windows.
- Даже под Windows, его использование по настоящему безопасно только для промежуточного хранения. Любое преобразование в обычный string делает строку небезопасной (а без этого не обойтись, так как почти все API не работают с SecureString).

Поэтому SecureString не стоит использовать ни в Blazor, ни в WPF на данный момент. Да, незащищенный пароль в памяти приложения может быть украден при XSS-атаке или при заражении вредоносным браузерным расширением. Это проблема технически сложно разрешима; механизмы защиты областей памяти хоть и существуют (например [Enclave API](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/enclaveapi/) в Windows), но они довольно новые и не интегрированы со всей остальной инфраструктурой ОС, браузера и веб-фреймфорков. Поэтому защититься тут можно только на уровне предотвращения XSS-атак и установки непроверенных расширений.

Comment: При наличии определенного навыка, [можно обойтись вообще без строк](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1245131/373567).