# Почему не работает подключенная viewmodel в основной viewmodel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Почему не работает?

View

```
<Window x:Class="Films.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
        xmlns:mvvm="clr-namespace:Films.Classes.MVVM"
        ResizeMode="NoResize"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">

    <Window.DataContext>
        <mvvm:MainViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>


    <Grid Height="Auto" Width="Auto">
        <Grid.Background>
            <ImageBrush x:Name="GridImage" Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="{Binding FilmViewModel.FilmPicture}"></ImageBrush>
        </Grid.Background>

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="20*" MinWidth="100" MaxWidth="740"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid x:Name="MainGrid" 
              Grid.Column="0"
              Height="Auto" Background="#2D474646">
            <Border Height="250" Width="280" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" CornerRadius="30,30,30,30" Background="#4C474646">
                <Grid DataContext="{Binding model}">
                    <Button Content="Acscess" Width="90" Height="27" Command="{Binding SignUp}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=Password}" x:Name="Autorization" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,45,0,0" />
                    <Button Content="Go by Guest" Width="76" Command="{Binding  SignByGhost}" x:Name="Guest" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,130,0,0"/>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Login}" Height="34" Width="171" Margin="0,0,0,100" FontSize="20" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                    <PasswordBox x:Name="Password" Width="136" Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,29"/>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
            <Border HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                    Height="120" Width="120" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" CornerRadius="0,100,0,0" Background="#B2FF0000">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding FilmViewModel.FilmName}" TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow"
                           VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="65" Width="80" Margin="0,0,17,10" Background="#00000000" 
                           FlowDirection="LeftToRight" FontSize="15" Foreground="#FFF9F9F9" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
            </Border>
        </Grid>

        <GridSplitter x:Name="Splinter" Grid.Column="0" Width="4" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,1,2,0" >
            <GridSplitter.Effect>
                <DropShadowEffect Direction="152" BlurRadius="10" ShadowDepth="2" Color="Gray" Opacity="1"></DropShadowEffect>
            </GridSplitter.Effect>
        </GridSplitter>

        <Grid x:Name="SettingsGrid"
              Grid.Column="1" 
              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <Button VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                    Height="40">
                <Button.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="Border">
                        <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="15"/>
                    </Style>
                </Button.Resources>
            </Button>
        </Grid>

    </Grid>

</Window>
```

Проблема тут

```
<Grid DataContext="{Binding model}">
                    <Button Content="Acscess" Width="90" Height="27" Command="{Binding SignUp}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=Password}" x:Name="Autorization" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,45,0,0" />
                    <Button Content="Go by Guest" Width="76" Command="{Binding  SignByGhost}" x:Name="Guest" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,130,0,0"/>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Login}" Height="34" Width="171" Margin="0,0,0,100" FontSize="20" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                    <PasswordBox x:Name="Password" Width="136" Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,29"/>
                </Grid>
```

Я пробовал без `DataConext`, через объект указывать `model.`, не работает.
Я проверяю роботоспособность кликом на кнопку, на неё должно  выводиться окошко.

MainViewModel:

```
class MainViewModel : INPC
{
    public AutorizationViewModel model
    {
       get;set;
    }
}
```

AutorizationViewModel(2ая ViewModel)

```
class AutorizationViewModel
    {
        private string login;
        public string Login
        {
            get => login;
            set
            {
                login = value;
            }
        }

        public ICommand SignUp
        {
            get
            {
                return new DelegateCommand((obj) =>
                {
                    System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("CALAM");
                });
            }
        }

        public ICommand SignByGhost
        {
            get
            {
                return new DelegateCommand((obj) =>
                {
                    // Залетаем в новое окно
                    System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("CALAM2");
                });
            }
        }

        private string GetPassword(object passwordObject)
        {
            var passwordBox = passwordObject as PasswordBox;
            if (passwordBox == null)
                return "";

            return passwordBox.Password;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Наверно, потому что у вас `model` не инициализирован (`null`)? Ну или вы его инициализируете уже после привязки основной VM. Вообще, у вас тут куча нарушений MVVM и других аспектов, советую исправить их.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. INPC, он у вас не используется.
2. model = null, этот класс нигде не создается, совсем.
3. класс VM должен быть публичным.
4. называйте свойства с большой буквы
5. содержимое класса INPC вы конечно же не покажете, но ничего страшного, я его придумаю сам

```
public class INPC : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

```
public class MainViewModel : INPC
{
    private AutorizationViewModel _model;

    public AutorizationViewModel Model
    {
        get => _model;
        set
        {
            _model = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        Model = new AutorizationViewModel();
    }
}
```

6. реализация команды сделана так, что ее экземиляр создается каждый раз заново при вызове команды. Это можно сделать 1 раз, а не каждый

```
public ICommand SignUp { get; } = new DelegateCommand(obj =>
{
    MessageBox.Show("CALAM");
});
```

7. А про привязку `PasswordBox` я уже писал здесь: [PasswordBox Bindings](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1245131/373567)