# Как расшифровать данные SHA512

Tags: c#, хеширование

Хочу хранить логин и пароль зашифрованно, в бд. Есть вот такой простенький код который шифрует мне пароль и логин в массив байтов. Как это как расшифровать? Знаю, что нужен ключ. Где мне его достать или придумать?

```
var login = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("login");
var password = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("password");

byte[] hashedLogin = null;
byte[] hashedPassword = null;

using (SHA512 shaM = new SHA512Managed())
{
    hashedLogin = shaM.ComputeHash(login);
    hashedPassword = shaM.ComputeHash(password);
}
```

Comment: Никак. Это алгоритм хеширования, а не криптографии. Единственный способ - это угадать через подбор слов, т.к. для одного и того же слова всегда будет одинаковый хеш

Comment: У вас же WPF, насколько я помню: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1245131/373567

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А Вам при проверке пароля не надо ничего расшифровывать.

Вам надо, чтобы введеный пользователем пароль зашифровали точно так же как и пароль при "придумывании пароля" - и сравнить хеши

Если хеши совпали - пароль правильный

Если не совпали - пароль неправильный

Именно для того, чтобы нигде не хранить пароли, и придумана эта схема.